# jQuery Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I keep getting the following error : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined`

the issue relates to this line: `posY = pos.top - $(window).scrollTop(),`

Although it's not actually damaging anything it is a bit of a pain to see.

I have tried to get the contents using : `var postest = inf.offset().top;` but what ends up happening instead is I get an offset error.

any ideas would be much appreciated.

```js
$(document).on("mouseenter", ":has('.infotip.ifixed')", function() {
  var inf = $(".infotip.ifixed");
  if (inf.length) {
    var itheight = $(this).children(".infotip").innerHeight(),
      pos = $(this).children(".infotip").parent().offset(),
      posY = pos.top - $(window).scrollTop(),
      posX = (pos.left - $(window).scrollLeft()) + 190,
      accuheight = (posY - itheight) + 150,
      divPos = {
        left: posX,
        top: accuheight
      };
    $(this).find(".infotip.ifixed").css(divPos);
  }
});
```

Comment: `$(this).children(".infotip").parent().offset()` is `undefined`.

Comment: which of these lines fails? can you see it in browser console?

Comment: @ddb Please see the question to see which line fails.

Answer (score 0):

My definition for `inf` was wrong.

```js
$(document).on("mouseenter", ":has('.infotip.ifixed')", function() {
  
  var inf = $(this).children(".infotip").parent();
  
  if (inf.length) {
    var postesty = inf.offset().top,
      postestx = inf.offset().top;
    
    var itheight = $(this).children(".infotip").innerHeight(),
      posY = postesty - $(window).scrollTop(),
      posX = (postestx - $(window).scrollLeft()) + 190,
      accuheight = (posY - itheight) + 150,
      divPos = {
        left: posX,
        top: accuheight
      };
    
    $(this).find(".infotip.ifixed").css(divPos);
  }
});
```